# How can i parse XML response by a function using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

i have a function giving me response in xml format , now i want to get the value of an attribute from that xml using jquery ? please help

```
var xml = api.getAllAvailableMarkups();

alert(xml) 
  xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );
  $xml = $( xmlDoc );
  $title = $xml.find( "URI" );


alert( $title.text() );
```

this is my code : 
1. I am getting object in first alert and in 2nd alert blank ..
2. as URI tag is available in response XML

3. this is respones i am getting from api.getAllAvailableMarkups();
   nishant.com

Comment: Well, your problem is obviously not related to XML parsing but rather `api.getAllAvailableMarkups()`

Comment: api.getAllAvailableMarkups is returning an XML response which i am unable to parse

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting first alert as undefined then obviously the response is not properly sent or the response is not properly received from the response. Check out on server side if the response if being sent. Or create a fiddle. Otherwise, your code is good . You have done good job their. Check out the api you used.

Comment: i am getting a response no problem on server side ,,,, issue is this $.parseXML takes String as input and i am providing XML there

Comment: did you get what you wanted then? I mean its solved?

Comment: what is API though? what kind of object?

Comment: im sorry but you need put that code about how you are getting the response from the server as well. Cause I have no way of knowing what is getAllAvailableMarkups(). I looked up if it is a method but feels like its your method defined somewhere

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><Mark><URI>http://nishant.com</URI></Mark>

Comment: this is what api.getAllAvailableMarkups() return